# How to add a control created in Blend in a Visual Studio WinForms Project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, blend

I have created a textbox in Blend and wanted to add it to my Visual Studio WinForms Project. This is how it looks like:
[image: image 1]

I built and ran(??) the project created in Blend for Visual Studio so I obtained this:
[image: image 2]

My questions are:

1. How do I add this textbox in my Visual Studio Project?
2. How can I disable the "Multiline" option from the textbox directly from Blend (can I? when I write more characters than the textbox allow it goes on a new line. I want it to continue on the same line)

Comment: Blend is for working with WPF / XAML, and AFAIK it is not "directly" compatible to Windows Forms. But as a workaround you could try using the [`ElementHost` control to host the WPF control in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms).

Comment: @bassfader I have added the WPF project to my Windows Forms Project and built it but when I want to select the element for the ElementHost I don't find it in the list